# C++ operator overloading affect in-class operator functions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

What if i overload the `!=` operator and use `class!=` inside one of other operator overloaders, does it accept it as non-overloaded or overloaded? I am trying to create a noob_ptr (a kind of custom-pointer wraper i am thinking of)

```
class noob_ptr 
 {
      private: //does this change the behaviour? public? protected?
      bool operator!=(noob_ptr x)
       {
         ...
        }
      bool operator,(noob_ptr y)
      {
         ...
         if(y!=z)...
         ...
      }
    ...
      }
```

Does below example cancel usage of overloaded-operator in my class?

```
class noob_ptr 
 {
      protected: //or public
      bool operator,(noob_ptr y) //yes, z is also a noob_ptr
      {
         ...
         if(y!=z)...
         ...
      }
    ...
      private: 
      bool operator!=(noob_ptr x)
       {
         ...
        }
      }
```

Comment: I don't get exactly what you mean, but it's common to implement `operator!=` in terms of `operator==`: `bool operator!=(const MyClass &lhs, const MyClass &rhs) {return !(lhs == rhs);}`

Comment: i mean while in the class , i use many overloaders. Do they change behaviour of other overloaders if they are used in?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Perhaps you can post an [actual program](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your question.

Comment: See my answer with member access restrictions below. In short, the answer to your second question is NO.

Comment: Why the hell you need to overload `operator,`? For a joyful debugging for others?

Comment: For a joyful developing a noob_ptr. I am trying to mimic some qbasic variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If type of `z` is also a `noob_ptr`, then the answer is YES, it will call the overloaded `operator !=` for your class.
Also, I'd suggest you this comparison method signature:

```
bool operator != (const noob_ptr& x) const;
```

so it can be used for constant pointers and also avoid object copying while calling the overloaded operator.

**UPD**: If you declare `operator !=` as private, then it'll be available in all member functions of `noob_ptr` class, friend classes and functions of `noob_ptr` class, and for all other usages will result in a compilation error with a message like: "operator != is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Answer (score 1):

If the operands you supply are ones for which the language's built-in `!=` will work, then that's what gets used. If they're of user-defined types, then it'll search for a user-defined `operator!=` that's defined for those types (or some types that support implicit conversion from those types).

Comment: I updated the question with some code. You saying my overloaders are primary or secondary target?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: Yes, assuming `y` and `z` both have type `noob_ptr`, then `if (y != z)` will use `noob_ptr::operator!=(noob_ptr)` to do the comparison (of, if it existed, a global `bool operator!=(noob_ptr a, noob_ptr b);`).

Answer (score 1):

C++ will always use the "best match" which is the closest in qualifiers, access specifiers such as private, scope, namespace, etc.

So, if there is a global namespace operator!= and a class one (that lacks the left-hand-side argument which is assumed to be the class& or const class& if the method is const -- which it should be), then inside the class (namespace) you will get the one inside the class.

If there is only one between the global namespace and the class, you will obviously get that one.

The following code demonstrates between global and class scope.  You can extend this by adding const qualifiers, etc.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Forward declaration to use without the class definition
class X;

bool operator!=(     int lhs, const X& rhs) {
  cout << "bool operator!=(     int lhs, const X& rhs)" << endl;
  return false;
}
bool operator!=(const X& lhs, const X& rhs) {
  cout << "bool operator!=(const X& lhs, const X& rhs)" << endl;
  return false;
}
bool operator!=(const X& lhs,      int rhs) {
  cout << "bool operator!=(const X& lhs,      int rhs)" << endl;
  return false;
}
// Note: Can't do: bool operator!=(int lhs, int rhs) -- already defined

class X {
private:
  int x;
public:
  X(int value) : x(value) { }

  bool operator !=(const X& rhs) {
    cout << "bool X::operator !=(const X& rhs)" << endl;
    return true;
  }

  bool operator !=(int rhs) {
    cout << "bool X::operator !=(int rhs)" << endl;
    return true;
  }

  void f() {
    X compare(1);
    cout << "X::f()" << endl;
    cout << (5 != 3) << endl;         // Uses built-in
    cout << (*this != 3) << endl;     // Uses member function
    cout << (*this != 1) << endl;     // Uses member function
    cout << (1     != *this) << endl; // There can be no member function, uses global namespace
    cout << (*this != compare) << endl;
  }
};


void f(const X& arg) {
  cout << "f()" << endl;
  X compare(1);
  cout << (5 != 3) << endl;         // Uses built in
  cout << (arg != 3) << endl;       // Uses global namespace
  cout << (arg != 1) << endl;       // Uses global namespace
  cout << (1   != arg) << endl;     // Uses global namespace
  cout << (arg != compare) << endl; // Uses global namespace
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  X x(1);
  x.f();
  f(x);
  return 0;
}
```